# Get props of function child component in tests with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Is there a way to get `show` **props** of `Child` component with `Enzyme`?

```
const [show] = useState(true)
<Parent>
  <Child show={show} />
</Parent>
```

both `Parent` and `Child` are function components

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use [dive](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html) and [props](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/props.html).

Suppose you have these components in an `App` component.

```js
// We create a shallow render of the component 
// that holds `const [show] = useState(true)` and renders `<Parent> ... </Parent>`
const wrapper = shallow(<App />);

expect(
  wrapper
    .find(Parent)
    .dive()
    .find(Child)
    .dive()
    .props().show
).to.equal(true);
```